# Create lists with data (with string type) in PHP

Tags: php, sorting

Need some help. I have a data array that i iterate over in a "foreach" loop. Here is an example:

```
array(1) {
  ["DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(publishedon), '%Y.%m')"]=>
  string(7) "1970.01"
}
array(1) {
  ["DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(publishedon), '%Y.%m')"]=>
  string(7) "2019.02"
}
array(1) {
  ["DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(publishedon), '%Y.%m')"]=>
  string(7) "2019.04"
}
array(1) {
  ["DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(publishedon), '%Y.%m')"]=>
  string(7) "2019.08"
}
```

I need to form a list at the front-end:

```
<ul>
   <li>1970.01</li>
</ul>
<ul>
   <li>2019.02</li>
   <li>2019.03</li>
   <li>2019.03</li>
   ...
</ul>
<ul>
   <li>2020.01</li>
</ul>
```

In other words, sort strictly by year. How can this be achieved? Here is a regular loop in which I iterate over the data:

```
foreach ($res as $month) {
    var_dump($month);
}
```

Comment: Your question is how order the data or how create list with data?

Comment: Please answer Simone's comment by stating a clear and not to long question as the title of your post. Right now, it's to general and not a question.

Comment: Create lists with data, but so that each list has only its own year. And the new year began with a new list (ul).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, try to build an unique array with all your date to begin with :

```php
$array = ["1970.01", "2020.01", ..., "2019.04"];
```

Then just sort your array as you wish : `sort($array)` (documentation [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php))

And to build your list just use a foreach where you check if the year change :

```php
$currentYear = '';
$list = '';
foreach ($array as $date) {
    // Get the year
    $getYear = explode('.', $date);
    $year = $getYear[0];

    // Check if same year or not
    if ($currentYear !== $year) {
        // Check if need to close last list
        if ($list !== '') {
            $list .= '</ul>';
        } 
        // Open new list
        $list .= '<ul>';

        // You change the current Year
        $currentYear = $year;
    }
    // Add the new date
    $list .= '<li>' . $date . '</li>';
}
// Add the last ul closure
$list .= '</ul>';

echo $list;
```

Here is the output using : `$array = ['1970.01', '2020.01', '2019.02', '2019.03', '2019.03'];` then `sort($array);` before the loop :

```html
<ul>
  <li>1970.01</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>2019.02</li>
  <li>2019.03</li>
  <li>2019.03</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>2020.01</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this code comes from a database query result.

First of all I would suggest you to use `AS field` in the query to avoid `DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(publishedon), '%Y.%m')` as array key.

Regarding your question: you can first make the database sort the dates for you using `ORDER BY publishedon ASC` and then flat the array to have mono-dimensional array:

```php
array(4) {
  string(7) "1970.01",
  string(7) "2019.02",
  string(7) "2019.04",
  string(7) "2019.08"
}
```

Instead, if you are looking for a plain PHP solution you can, e.g., flat your array, convert your strings to dates with [DateTime::createFromFormat](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) and sort the array with one of the PHP's built-in functions:

```php
$array = [
    ["DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(publishedon), '%Y.%m')" => "2019.04"],
    ["DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(publishedon), '%Y.%m')" => "2019.08"],
    ["DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(publishedon), '%Y.%m')" => "2019.02"],
    ["DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(publishedon), '%Y.%m')" => "1970.01"],
];

$res = [];

// flat the array and convert each value in DateTime
foreach ($array as $a) {
   $res[] = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y.m', $a["DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(publishedon), '%Y.%m')"]);
}

sort($res); // sort the array

foreach ($res as &$r) { // get back the sorted dates as strings in custom format
    $r = $r->format('Y.m');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This method passes through the array twice, so perhaps not as efficient as a single pass, but the code is more condensed.

First it builds am array grouped by year, the it loops over this array and uses `implode()` to build the `<li>` items from the list of entries...

```
$groups = [];
foreach ( $res as $yearMonth )  {
    list($year, $month) = explode(".", $yearMonth);
    $groups[$year][] = $yearMonth;
}

foreach ($groups as $group) {
    echo "<ul><li>".implode("</li><li>", $group)."</li></ul>".PHP_EOL;
}
```

If you cannot sort the data in your SQL query, just add `sort($res);` before running this code.